# Python - GCP Cloud Function issue with getting yesterdays date

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud

I have a requirement of getting yesterdays date in my GCP Cloud Function which is written Python 3.9

This is the snippet I am using

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
cur_dt = datetime.today()
str_dt = str((datetime.today() - timedelta(1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
print(cur_dt)
print(str_dt)
```

This is working fine in Jupyter notebook. But if I place this same code in my cloud function, it fails to compile.

This is the error message I am getting: - Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code.

Would be of great help if anyone can help me fixing this error. This is strange and I dont understand why CLoud function isnt accepting something that is working fine in Jupyter notebook

Many Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You don't respect the Cloud Functions schema. You have to expose a function, not a piece of script

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you need to follow the Cloud Functions schema which requires an entrypoint function that takes in the `request` parameter. [Here is a codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-functions-python-http#2) that walks through setting up a Cloud Function.

Your code should be updated to the following:

```py
# imports 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# entrypoint function with request param
def get_time(request):
  cur_dt = datetime.today()
  str_dt = str((datetime.today() - timedelta(1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
  # can still print here if you want
  return str_dt
```

If you are going through the UI make sure to update the entrypoint field to be `get_time` or whatever you name your entrypoint function.